# Will changing the upper case to lower case can shorten the length of string?

Tags: c++

Will changing the upper case to lower case can shorten the length of string?

```
void lower(char *s)
{
  int i;
  for (i=0;i<strlen(s);i++)
     if(s[i])>='A' && s[i]<='Z')
       s[i]-=('A'-'a');
}
```

Comment: What is the question? Whether changing a string to lower case can shorten the string *in general* (which might depend on the encoding and possibly the locale), or whether your specific code snippet will alter the length of the string?

Comment: you should be using std::tolower instead; with your code it is pretty obvious: you don't change it, so the length stays the same :)

Comment: If you are using C++ then you should use `std::string`, `tolower` etc. and move to a higher level of abstraction.

Comment: Something wrong with `std::string`?

Answer (score 2):

No, it shouldn't.

Some other things to note:

1. You're calculating `strlen` on each iteration of the loop, try saving it to a variable
2. You assume the string is properly null-terminated; you will overrun if it's not

Comment: How would you propose to stabilize this loop against missing null-termination? Sorry if this sounds dumb, but I don't really see a way.

Comment: The only safe way I can think of is to change the API: `lower(char *s, size_t maxlen)`.This requires the surrounding code to work with similar bounded string functions, e.g. `strncpy` instead of `strcpy`. Without this assumption I don't see a way either.

Comment: 1. Let the compiler take care of the optimisations.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal, in this case I'd say optimize yourself. Since you are modifying `s` within the loop an optimizer is very likely to decide not to do this for you. Consider that unless the optimizer can work through your calculation and decide a null could not be assigned to `s` it __cannot__ optimize away the call to `strlen`

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y: Well, true.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are working in ASCII, no, you're obviously doing 1-on-1 replacement. Should you ever change the code to support UTF-8: Maybe.

Answer (score 1):

If you just replace one character for another, as you do, then the resulting string will still have the same size. Type `char` is always defined to be one byte in C or C++.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the case of a string could change the length, if it is done
correctly.  In German, for example, the two character string "SS" will
become the single character string "ß" in certain contexts (but not in
others, e.g.: "STRASSE" -> "Straße", but "GASSE"->"Gasse").  Changing
case correctly is decidedly non-trivial however, and very locale
specific.  And there's no real support for it in the standard.

The code you post won't change the length, but then, it's far from
correctly: depending on the encoding, it may change some non-alphabetic
characters as well (the alphabet is not always contiguous), and it will
definitely fail to convert some alphabetic characters, e.g. 'Ä', 'Ö' and
'Ü' in Swedish.

Answer (score -1):

This code **doesn't change the length** of the string. However there are **problems** with the code: Calculating `strlen()` with every iteration, which is redundant.
    Store the result in the a variable and use it in the loop

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I messed up. Edited now.